# Rampup calculation in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

How to I calculate Ramp-up time in JMeter

Test Case : Expecting 84 users per 60 minutes on the home page.
I have set following thread properties :

No. of Threads : 84

Ramp-up Time - ? [I am not sure what to set]

Loop count - Forever

Scheduler - 3600 Seconds[60 Minutes]

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best way to control the number of threads in your load test is to use one of the [Custom Thread Groups](https://jmeter-plugins.org/?search=jpgc-casutg) plugins to profile ramp-up and steady states.  In your example the [Ultimate Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/) seems to be appropriate.  Here is an example of how you can configure that thread group to gradually ramp up to 84 threads and then sustain that load against your target test application:
[image: Ultimate thread group depiction of 84 thread continuous load with gradual ramp-up]

In the above example your load can be configured to ramp up gradually over a period of time (*i.e.*, 5 minutes), and then sustained for any desired duration (here for 600 seconds or 10 minutes).  When using the Ultimate Thread Group, a discrete loop count is not necessary as at any point exactly 84 threads for the sustained steady-state will be active at all times — when one thread finishes, another is immediately started to take its place.

There is a good article that covers [using JMeter Custom Thread Groups here](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2022/10/jmeter-custom-thread-groups/) that can explain more of the details to setting up the Ultimate Thread Group and related thread groups with profiling capabilities available in the same Custom Thread Groups package.  This happens to be one of the most popular JMeter plugins that is used today.

Answer (score 0):

The main idea is increasing the load **gradually** so you won't kick off all 84 users at once but rather start with 1, after certain time add another one, etc. This time you will be able to correlate increasing load with other [metrics](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html) like response time, throughput, number of errors, etc. It will also give you the [saturation](http://hd-performance.blogspot.com/2010/05/saturation-point.html) point and the bottleneck in case of problems.

If you don't have better ideas you can try sticking to [JMeter documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#thread_group):

> Ramp-up needs to be long enough to avoid too large a work-load at the start of a test, and short enough that the last threads start running before the first ones finish (unless one wants that to happen).
>
> Start with **Ramp-up = number of threads** and adjust up or down as needed.

If you want my personal piece of advice I would:

1. Increase the load for first 20 minutes
2. Leave 84 users up and running for another 20 minutes
3. Last 20 minutes I would gradually decrease the load to see how does the system react

More information: [JMeter Ramp-Up Period: The Ultimate Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-period)